# How to repeat a list n times and reverse its elements alternately?

Tags: pandas, numpy

My input is a list of numbers that are not necessarily sorted but for the example I made a simple one :

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to repeat it n times horizontaly but when i is odd we need to reverse the list :

```
# [[0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
#  [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3],
#  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#  [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1],
#  [4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0]]
```

For that I made the code below but I'm not proud of it.

```
final = []

for i in range(6):
    if i%2 == 0:
        final.append(my_list)
    else:
        final.append(my_list[::-1])
        
final = list(zip(*final))
```

I heard that numpy and pandas are more suitable for this kind of operations.

Do you guys have any idea how to do it ? I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) (or [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)) and indexing:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
N = 6

# repeat the array
out = np.tile(np.array(my_list)[:, None], (1, N))
# or
# out = np.repeat(np.array(my_list)[:, None], N, axis=1)

# invert the odd columns
out[:, 1::2] = out[::-1, 1::2]
```

Or with a small hack that might be faster for large `N`, form a pair of columns in the ascending/descending order, then `tile` it to the closest upper even value, and slice to remove the last column if even:

```
N = 6
a = np.array(my_list)
out = np.tile(np.c_[a, a[::-1]], (1, (N+1)//2))[:, :N]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4],
       [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1],
       [4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0]])
```

###### timings

for `N = 10_000`:

```
# first approach
44.9 µs ± 1.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# second approach
24.7 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# list(zip(*(my_list[::-1] if i%2 else my_list for i in range(N))))
1.33 ms ± 82.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Or a python one-liner for fun: `out = list(zip(*(my_list[::1-2*(i%2)] for i in range(N))))`

Comment: Honestly I like your two approaches but can you explain to me please this  `1-2*(i%2)` ?

Comment: Another way: `N = -(-len(my_list)//2);
[[i, j]*N for i, j in zip(my_list, my_list[::-1])]`

Comment: @VERBOSE `1-2*(i%2)` is a way to have `1` if even and `-1` if odd. That's a hacky shortcut that shouldn't be used in real life as it's less explicit than your loop in the original post.

Comment: `out = list(zip(*(my_list[::-1] if i%2 else my_list for i in range(N))))` for a cleaner python one-liner